# How to check the component type of a component's props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

I've got quite a simple `FormControlLabel`, with components for the 'control' and the 'label':

```
  const MyComponent = () =>
    <FormControlLabel
      control={<CheckBox />}
      label={<Typography>Check please!</Typography}
    />
```

And in my tests I'd like to check I have the right components, where `wrapper` is my component from above:

```
it('uses a checkbox for the control', function() {
  expect(wrapper.prop('control').type()).to.equal(Checkbox);
})
```

Except I get `TypeError wrapper.prop(...).type is not a function.

If I print out what `wrapper.prop('control')` is I get an object with a type object but not a function.

If I wrap each prop with `shallow` I am now equality checking the components and they don't match. (This is not what I expected to have to do)

I can't see how to get [`type()`](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/type.html) to work.

How can I check the type of the props?

Comment: Have you looked into Chai-Enzyme? https://github.com/producthunt/chai-enzyme#typefunc

Comment: Not sure if wrapper.prop('control') will work with this, but try `expect(wrapper.prop('control')).to.have.type(Checkbox)` with Chai-enzume.

Comment: Or maybe this `expect(wrapper).to.have.prop('index', Checkbox)`, have not tested this but might work. (with Chai-Enzyme)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get it working with:

```
expect(wrapper.prop('control').type).to.deep.equal(Checkbox);
```

Although I do not know if this is the neatest way to do so.